# Отложить выполнение функции (фоновая функция)

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Пытаюсь на питоне реализовать выполнение отложенной функции (фоновую функцию), которая бы не прерывала выполнение других функций.

Суть функции - через 1 час/день изменить значение в строке коллекции `MongoDB`.

Я стал изучать `asyncio`, но и в нем не нашел решения. Видите ли, выполнение таких функций блокируют мой синхронный код. Пока что я понял, как запустить N функций одновременно, но весь код, который идет после запуска, не продолжит выполняться, пока не завершатся все N функций. Расскажите, пожалуйста, как не блокировать код?

```
import asyncio



def rocket(value):
    rocketName = value
    print(rocketName)


async def print_nums():
    num = 1
    while num < 10:
        print(num)
        num += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


async def main():

    tasks = []
    for i in range(10): # запускаю 10 функций за раз
        tasks.append( asyncio.create_task(print_nums()) )


    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    print("i = " + str(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
    rocket("myFirstRocket") # не выполнится, пока работат строка выше
```

Comment: Для этого вам не нужен `asyncio`, используйте [потоки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), или запускайте скрипт по крону. После завершения работы функции, вызванной из `asyncio.run`, цикл событий тоже завершается.

Comment: Приведенный вами код имеет мало общего с описанием проблемы. Если по коду: вам всю асинхронную работу стоит кинуть в отдельный поток, тогда блокировки не будет. Но скорее всего для реальной задачи требуется что-то другое. Попробуйте переформулировать задачу, потому что пока непонятно, какая работа непрерывно выполняется скриптом.

Comment: @mkkik Я пишу статистику для телеграм группы. Асинхронно реагирую на ивенты от телегам бота. Когда пользователь отправляет сообщение "/start" боту, в коллекции MongoDB я ставлю значение ожидания, пока бот добавится в группу, равным True.

Если пройдет час, я хочу это значение сделать равным False.

Это лишь один пример.

Comment: @extrn спасибо! Посмотрю потоки тоже

Comment: Ну тогда точно отдельный поток + таймер.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого вам не нужен asyncio, используйте [потоки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), или запускайте
скрипт по крону. После завершения работы функции, вызванной из
`asyncio.run`, цикл событий тоже завершается.

[@extrn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1003408/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f#comment1699413_1003408)